# Как вырезать часть строки до и после определённых символов

Tags: java, строки

Никак не могу понять. Везде мануалы с индексом, но индекса мы не знаем, так как строки разной длины.

**Пример:** Есть URL адрес с метками, например [https://start.spring.io/?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign={campaignid}&utm_content={adgroupid}&utm_term={creative}](https://start.spring.io/?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=%7Bcampaignid%7D&utm_content=%7Badgroupid%7D&utm_term=%7Bcreative%7D)

Задача получить значение находящееся между **https://start.spring.io/?utm_source=** и **&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign={campaignid}&utm_content={adgroupid}&utm_term={creative}**, то есть **youtube** и записать его в отдельную строку

Всё что нашёл - либо не работает, либо через регулярку, которую я не знаю, либо через индекс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для "простого" поиска в строке можно использовать перегруженный метод [`String::indexOf(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) и [`String::indexOf(String str, int from)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int)), который впрочем зависит от регистра.

Также в общем случае может понадобиться декодировать значение параметра при помощи метода [`URLDecoder::decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

```java
public static String getUrlParam(String url, String paramName) {
    String param = paramName + "="; // включить знак = в имя параметра
    int start = url.indexOf(param); // искать параметр

    if (start == -1) return null; // параметр не найден
    int end = url.indexOf("&", start += param.length()); // искать конец значения
    if (end == -1) end = url.length(); // значение в конце входного УРЛа

    try {
        return URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(start, end), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unsencex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(unsencex);
    }
}
```

---

Аналогично можно искать при помощи регулярного выражения вида `paramName + "=([^&]*)(&|$)"`, тогда будет несколько проще реализовать поиск независимый от регистра:

```java
public static String getUrlParam(String url, String paramName) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(paramName + "=([^&]*)(&|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);

    if (!m.find()) return null;

    try {
        return URLDecoder.decode(m.group(1), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unsencex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(unsencex);
    }
}
```

Смысл регулярки: после имени параметра и знака "равно" искать от 0 символов, не равных `&`, пока не будет найден разделитель параметров `&` или конец строки `$`.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле вам нужно не просто получить часть строки, вам нужно парсить URL. Есть огромное количество готовых решений , но если вы хотите написать это самостоятельно, то метод будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public static Map<String, String> splitQuery(URL url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {        
    Map<String, String> queryParams = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String param : url.getQuery().split("&")) {
        int idx = param.indexOf("=");
        queryParams.put(URLDecoder.decode(param.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8"), 
                URLDecoder.decode(param.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return queryParams;
}
```

Вызываете его , передавая new URL("...")(Вместо троеточия подсталяете свой url), получаете Map, содержащую все параметры запроса. По ключу дергаете нужный.

Что касается готовых решений, все зависит от того, что вы используете в своем проекте:

```
1)URLEncodedUtils for Apache http client or URLEncodedUtils for Apache http client 5
2)UriComponentsBuilder for Spring
3)HttpUrl for OkHttp
4)QueryStringDecoder for Netty
```

В своей практике больше не встречал, но уверен, что это далеко не исчерпывающий список.
Выбирайте на свой вкус))